# Missed my flight because I didn't get e-mail with boarding pass

Tags: airlines, check-in, compensation, missed-flights

This must be the weirdest "missed the flight" situation ever. We were four, traveling from Alicante to Keflavik. I checked in online with the app and got "you are now checked-in" and allocated seats 20E and 20F.

When we arrived at the airport, it said "boarding" and the woman at check-in says the flight will leave 30 minutes earlier and we should have gotten an e-mail about it. None of us received any email. She tells us the check-in process has closed and tells us to rush to the security line and scan the online check-in code. There, I realized I never had any email with a QR code.

After some fuss the staff says, "Sorry, you are stuck in Alicante." The strange thing is that there was a 30-minute delay, but not a 30-minute earlier departure time. Is the airline to blame or the airport?

**EDIT:**

Departure time was 01:05 - We were at the airport 23:45 - at the counter 23:50 - There was a line - the last people in front of us was having some trouble and talking to the woman at the counter - After 10 minutes we asked where they were going - Appeared they were on a totally different flight - Than we talked to the woman at the counter and she said "why didn´t you come in front of the line before" and told us check-in was closed.... She told us to run to the front of the security lane - our two friends had QR code and it was scanned - When I opened my app the QR code was gone - tech error...

Comment: How many minutes before scheduled departure time were you at the check-in counter?  Airlines have minimum check-in times and if you were later than their standard, then you won't have any success taking action.  If you were there before you were required to report, you'll have a good argument to make.

Comment: By checked in online with the app, do you mean a dedicated app from the airline on your mobile device, or the airline's website? In my experience, if it's a dedicated app, you won't get an email. It is of course still their job to notify you of any changes to schedule.

Comment: @user16259 only app I know is the KLM one, which is both boarding card and gives notifications about schedule and gate changes

Comment: What is the airline? What was the (original) scheduled departure time? At what time did you get to the check-in counter? Did you have any bags to check? If so, you should have gotten a boarding pass at that point. If you used the app, you should have had access to the boarding pass QR code directly in the app.

Comment: when you check in with the app you get a boarding pass, which contains a QR code. Why do you say you don't have a qr code?? you should try to explain better because it's not very clear. Please specify also airline and what you used to check in, app or website

Comment: departure time was 01:05 - We were at the airport 23:45 - at the counter 23:50 - There was a line - the last people in front of us was having some trouble and talking to the woman at the counter - After 10 minutes we asked where they was going - Appeared they were on a total different flight - Than we talked to the woman at the counter and she said "why didn´t you come in front of the line before" and told us check-in was closed.... She told us to run to the front of the security lane - our two friends had QR code and it was scanned - When I opened my app the QR code was gone - tech error...

Comment: @IngþórIngólfsson Welcome to TSE. I think we are all having a hard time understanding what the situation is. If there are four of you, why were you only allocated two seats? Did you request your boarding pass by email or to display in the app? If you chose email, what QR code are you talking about when you say you opened the app? If you chose the app, why does not receiving the email make a difference? Please [edit] the post to clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify which airline you were flying (Wow or Primera Air Nordic both have ALC-KEF flights at 1:05 on some days) and the exact date? The flight on Monday (night from Sunday to Monday) was definitely not moved forward in either case, and check-in counters are supposed to close 45 minutes before departure (so 00:20) for both. Did you have any checked baggage? Are you sure you went to the right check-in counter (as there may have been two flights for the same destination at the same time)?

Comment: Neither the airport or the airlines is "to blame". You are to blame, since you didn't keep up with your flight.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.